# Trouble Making Bargraph in R with GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just starting to work with R and I want to make a column bargraph comparing the density of individuals for 3 different species over multiple months. Every time I enter the code for making a bargraph it outputs a graph with all the same y-values for each species in every month. The code I used is below. I first had to gather my data utilizing tidyr in order to make the graph as the data was organized by a column for each individual species. How can I make the bargraph display my y-values for each data point? Thanks.

```
ggplot(Bargraphstuff, aes(fill=Species, y='Density per 10 cm Octocoral', x=Month)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data for clarification? Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to share your data.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It looks like you are trying to pass a y label as an aesthetic. Maybe you just want `aes(fill=Species, x=Month)` and then at the end put `+ylab('Density per 10 cm Octocoral')`

Comment: Hey Josh, try aes_string(fill='Species', y='Density per 10 cm Octocoral', x='Month'). You are passing a string 'Density per 10 cm Octocoral' as a y value, hence you get always the same output